# Regex Match if there is space in front

Tags: regex

I need a regex which matches with 1 to 6 length digits which is easy `\d{1,6}`, however I need avoid if there is longer number than 6 digits.

For example, it should match `233` in sentence, `my id is 233`, but it should not match `my id is 222334444`

It should only match if there is space before first digit of number.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Its hard to tell what the expected character is on either side.

Generally, it could be done using word boundary `\b\d{1,6}\b`

Answer (score 0):

Use [lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

```
(?<=^|\s)\d{1,6}(?!\d)
```

Comment: You can suffice for word boundaries. `\b\d{1,6}\b`

Comment: hwnd suggestion work better, because Rawning's suggestion matched with the following string "32309fdkjf"

Answer (score 0):

How about?

[Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nK3zB3/1)

```
(?<!\d)\d{1,6}$
```